# Getting no such column :bookmarks in the following many-to-many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have a `Post` and an `User` model. I'm trying to add a `Bookmark` mode, so that users can bookmark posts. I'm using a `join model`:

**schema.rb:**

```
create_table "bookmarks", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "bookmarker_id"
  t.integer  "bookmarked_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",    :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at",    :null => false
end
```

**bookmark.rb:**

```
class Bookmark < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :bookmarked_id

  belongs_to :bookmarker, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :bookmarked, class_name: "Post"

  validates :bookmarker_id, presence: true
  validates :bookmarked_id, presence: true
end
```

**post.rb:**

```
has_many :bookmarks, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :bookmarkers, :through => :bookmarks
```

**user.rb:**

```
has_many :bookmarks, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :bookmarked_posts, :through => :bookmarks, source: :bookmarked
```

I tried to test the association in the terminal but I get this:

```
1.9.3-p0 :007 > user.bookmarks
  Bookmark Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "bookmarks".* FROM "bookmarks" WHERE "bookmarks"."user_id" = 1
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: bookmarks.user_id: SELECT "bookmarks".* FROM "bookmarks"  WHERE "bookmarks"."user_id" = 1
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't specify foreign_key, exception clearly said

```
no such column: bookmarks.user_id
```

just add

```
has_many :bookmarks, :foreign_key => 'bookmarker_id'
```

Comment: I should do that to the `User` model right? Should I do that to the Post model as well? (`:foreign_key => 'bookmarked_id'`)

Answer (score 1):

There is no foreign key bookmarks

do as follow;

```
rails g migration add_user_id_to_bookmarks user_id:integer
```

then do

```
has_many :bookmarks, :foreign_key => 'bookmarker_id'
```

Comment: I think I don't have to add `user_id` since I already have `bookmarker_id`?